# Problems with UDP in windows 10. UWP

Tags: c#, udp, win-universal-app, datagram

I am having the following problem:
I am communicating 2 different machines in local network with UDP.

In one side I have a Windows 7 machine with 4.5 framework installed. I am using the class System.Net
with this code:

```
 public static void UDPWriter()

    {

        Task.Run(async () =>

        { 
            byte[] data = new byte[10000];
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Pars("192.168.0.16"), 5002);

            Socket udpClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);


            udpClient.Connect(ipep);

            while (true)

            {
                await Task.Delay(24);
                string input = packagetosend;
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
                var receivedResults = udpClient.Send(data, SocketFlags.None);

            }

        });

    }
```

In the other side I am working with a Windows 10 Universal App with this code:

```
   async static private void EnablerListener()
        {
            //Click

            HostName hostname = new HostName("192.168.0.16");
            listener = new DatagramSocket();
            listener.Control.InboundBufferSizeInBytes=10000;


            listener.MessageReceived += socket_MessageReceived;


            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync("5002");

        }

       static void socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {

            // Message received. Place your logic here

        }
```

As soon as I send a "small" package ( my theory is that less than the MTU) I receive correctly what is sent.

The problem comes with I my udp package is fragmented. When I send 1 packages that is splitted in 4 ( I have seen it in Wireshark) the Windows 10 software do not receive anything. I have tried changing listener.Control.Donotfragment( maybe I am using it wrong) but it seems not working.
UPDATE1:
In wireshark I receive this message
time-to-live exceeded (fragment reassembly time exceeded) Only some packages in Wireshark, others are succesfully reassembled ( almost all)

Comment: You are setting the DontFragment property on the listener which means it will reject any fragmented packets received. Does it work if you set this to false on the listener?

Comment: No. I have tried all the parameters in Datagramsocket.control. I have made all possible combinations, in listener and sender. I will try with a different router today to see if its hardware issue that make checksums wrong or something similar.

Comment: time-to-live exceeded (fragment reassembly time exceeded) I receive this message in wireshark

Comment: You are only listening to multicast packets? `listener.Control.MulticastOnly = true;`

Comment: No sorry its my fault. I have done multiple cases and I forgot it there

Comment: Have you tried starting from the UWP sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket

Comment: @MattC the code is from there. I did not run that app but its exactly the same code. For me its a .netcore bug.

Comment: @ronconsoda did you finally find a solution on that? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hi @John, I am sorry but no. I have tried to report it, but if I am honest I have tried to do it in Github .netcore and they rejected it. Finally i have chosen another way to do it with WCF. :S

Comment: ok @ronconsoda I also posted to the msdn forum but still no reply...

Comment: hi @John, this is the  issue if you want to continue :
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8068#issuecomment-215539480

Answer (score 3):

Local machine IPC using Loopback on UWP is restricted. I recently ran in to this problem myself. Perhaps consider a different approach like App-to-App Communication - https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-765

From the DatagramSocket sample:

> Note  Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot
>   normally be used for interprocess communication between a Universal
>   Windows Platform (UWP) app and a different process (a different UWP
>   app or a desktop app) because this is restricted by network isolation.
>   Network communication using an IP loopback address is allowed within
>   the same process for communication purposes in a UWP app. For more
>   information, see How to set network capabilities.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket (towards the bottom)

Comment: Just came across this - 
Windows Loopback Exemption Manager http://loopback.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have run it in two different machines. the issue is, when you have only one packet, runs ok, with one packet fragmented( due to its side) it do not receive anything

Comment: note that loopback exceptions work only for client sockets, not server (listening) ones

Comment: so, how you test your application? do you need 2 computers? I am little bit confused..