# What needs to be done to receive UDP datagrams in UWP app?

Tags: sockets, xamarin.forms, uwp, udpclient, xamarin.uwp

In my Xamarin.Forms app for UWP I have the following simple code to receive a UDP datagram:

```
using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(port))
{
  var datagram = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
}
```

For testing purposes I need to run this app from within Visual Studio and from the same computer send a datagram to the app with some (non-UWP) terminal program. But it doesn't work - `ReceiveAsync()` never returns.

I know that UWP prohibits loopback communication by default, but for debugging it should be possible according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44990978/487356.

In the UWP project I enabled the "Internet (Client)", "Internet (Client & Server)" and "Private Networks (Client & Server)" capabilities. Also I enabled "Allow local network loopback" in the debug settings. And using the CheckNetIsolation tool I was able to verify that my app is listed under LoopbackExempt. So this all looks good, but I still can't receive any UDP datagrams.

Is there something else I need to do for this to work?

---

**Edit**
Reading a bit more about this, it looks like receiving data from the same machine is prohibited even when the app is listed under LoopbackExempts, see [Problems with UDP in windows 10. UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832880/problems-with-udp-in-windows-10-uwp#comment78815143_37086151). This is really annoying!

So I guess the follow-up question would be: What is a good (preferrably connection-less) alternative for IPC?

Comment: What your understanding is correct. 'Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot be used for interprocess communication (between two different apps) in a Windows Runtime app since this is restricted by network isolation.' **'But Network communication using an IP loopback address is allowed within an app within the same process for communication purposes'**. So, if it's for testing purposes, you could do like the official UWP [DatagramSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket). Listening and connect in the same app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For testing purposes I need to run this app from within Visual Studio and from the same computer send a datagram to the app with some (non-UWP) terminal program. But it doesn't work - ReceiveAsync() never returns.

If this is just for testing purposes, you can use CheckNetIsolation tool to temporarily enable receiving connections from the same machine:

`CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -is -n=<AppContainer or Package Family>`

However, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback), the tool will have to be continuously running as admin. We use this mechanism for unit testing our code and it works very well.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Also it really depends what port you're using. I had to try a few until a found one that worked.